# Normalizing integers

Tags: algorithm, java-7

I have a list of integers and I want to normalize them so that their sum is let's say 100. So for instance `(1, 1, 1, 1) --> (25, 25, 25, 25)`. This is relatively easy to achieve:

```
int sum = calcSum(list);
double factor = 100.0 / sum;
List<Integer> newList = Lists.newArrayList();
for (Integer i : list) {
  newList.add(i*factor);
}
```

This works as long as the sum is a divisor of 100. Unfortunately this maps `(1, 2) --> (33, 66)` instead of `(1, 2) --> (33, 67)`. I can add rounding to my solution

```
newList.add(i*factor); --> newList.add(Math.round(i*factor));
```

Unfortunately this still has the problem that `(1, 1, 1) --> (33, 33, 33)`. I realize that in this case I need to add some sort of tiebreaker and arbitrarily choose one of the entries to be 34. Let's say the ratios were `(0.334, 0.333, 0.333)` I would want to choose the first element and not make an arbitrary choice. Even in the case of a perfect tie, choosing one element at random to increment by 1 isn't good enough because I might have to increment by more than 1.

I could probably come up with an inelegant algorithm that repeatedly chooses the max (without choosing the same element twice and with an arbitrary tiebreaker) and increments it until the sum is 100. Is there a nicer algorithm to do this?

Comment: It looks like you can use the idea behind the Bresenham algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of floating point division, you can use an integer division with remainder.

```
private static int [] divide(int ... num) {
    int [] ret = new int[num.length];
    int sum = sum(num);
    int rem = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
        int count = num[i]*100 + rem;
        ret[i] = count / sum;
        rem = count % sum;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

As you can see, we always carry the remainder to the next iteration and add it back. By always feeding the remainder in the next iteration we always know when we need to add a "leap number" in to reach the exact total score of 100.

The only problem here is that the extra number will be added to the last element, but I'll let you figure out how to change that. :)

*This idea of keeping track of your error and feeding it back is a powerful general strategy, used in many algorithms, most notably in the [Bresenham line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm).*

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll have to think about it a bit but looks good.

Comment: might want to add  (in python) `m[indices[0]] += np.round(remainder)`, where `indices` are a randomly shuffled set of indices for the input array, before returning the result incase there is a left over amount in the `remainder` value.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could always set the last integer to the missing amount:

```
int currentSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size - 2, i++) {
    newList.add(list.get(i) * factor);
    currentSum += list.get(i);
}
newList.add(sum - currentSum);
```

Comment: This will guarantee that the sum is 100 but won't necessarily always increment the max. But is elegant so if there are no other solutions this might work.

Comment: This will also add all the remainder to the last element.